# How to read data from specific block in azure blob?

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to read data from specific block in azure blob using Java?

Can someone help me with this?

I managed to read the whole blob and to list the blocks in it, but cannot find a way to read data from the specific block.

```
 public class App2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DefaultAzureCredential defaultCredential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build();

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .endpoint("https://{storage-account}.blob.core.windows.net/")
                .credential(defaultCredential)
                .buildClient();

        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("insights-logs-networksecuritygroupflowevent");

        for (BlobItem blobItem : blobContainerClient.listBlobs()) {
            BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(blobItem.getName());

            BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient();
            List<Block> list = blockBlobClient.listBlocks(BlockListType.COMMITTED).getCommittedBlocks();

            list.forEach(block -> {
                System.out.println(block.getName() + ", " + block.getSizeLong());
            });

            blobClient.downloadToFile("blob" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".json");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using [Azure Blob Storage client library for Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli#code-examples)? Can you please share your current code?

Comment: I've updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `downloadToFile` method of the [BlobClientBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blobclientbase?view=azure-java-stable) class.

[Here an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli#download-blobs) from the [Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6886501/markus-meyer) documentation link.

Comment: I already have this in place, but my question is how can I check which data a specific block contains? Because these files can be large, I'm trying to figure out how can I split them and track which block is processed (I'm sending the data to data center) and which not. If that can be done.